# Google Gson not deserializing simple object with ArrayList properly

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am trying out Gson, but I cannot get past this issue.

What ends up happening is the Network class gets created (my JSON root) and three layers are added. These 3 Layers do not have the right "input" or "output" values set (both are 0).

**I am expecting three layers with input and output values above 0.**

Below is my JSON and the code for the classes and Gson.

**Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Is it my JSON structure or Java structure?**

Gson code:

```
try(Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(ModelLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.json"), "UTF-8")){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Network n = gson.fromJson(reader, Network.class);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

I have a very very simple JSON like so **(EDITED per discussion below)**:

```
{
  "layers" : [

    {"layer":
      {"input":300,
      "output":8000}
    },
    {"layer2":
      {"input":300,
      "output":8000}
    },
    {"layer3":
      {"input":300,
      "output":8000}
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the Layer class:

```
public class Layer {

    int input;
    int output;
    float[][] weights;
    float[] inputs;
    float[] outputs;

    public Layer(int input, int output) {
        ...constructor code initializes vars...
    }

    public void setInput(int input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void setOutput(int output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public void setInputs(float[] inputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }

    public void setWeight(float[][] weights) {
        this.weights = weights;
    }
}
```

And here is the class that contains an array list of layers:
import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Network {

    ArrayList<Layer> layers;

    public Network() {
        layers = new ArrayList<Layer>();
    }

    public void addLayer(Layer l) {
        layers.add(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the `layer`, `layer2`, and `layer3` be mapped to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis a layer class.

Comment: Why? Where do you have anything named `layer`, `layer2`, or `layer3` in your group of classes?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have a Layer class and my Network has an ArrayList of type Layer.

Comment: Let me rephrase. You have this expectation that the JSON pair named `input` will be mapped to a `Layer` object's field named `input`. Ok, let's go up a level. Which field will the JSON pair named `layer1` be mapped to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis layer1, labeled as "layer" in my JSON is defined as the first object in an array labeled "layers". "layers" is defined in my Network class as an ArrayList of type Layer. So my expectation is that Gson maps the first element in my "layers" array to a Layer object.

Comment: Ok, "acceptable" expectation. Now back it up with quotes from documentation you've read. What makes you believe that's the behavior Gson should exhibit here?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "Gson dynamically discovers (through reflection) the class and its fields" http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/ , I expected it to discover the type Layer since my ArrayList can only be of type Layer. It seems to be able to for the first layer at least because it adds one.

Comment: _and its fields_. There are no fields named `layer`, `layer2`, or `layer3`. Basically this mapping. `layers` in your JSON is an array that contains one JSON object with three members. That should correspond to a Java POJO with three fields of type `Layer`, named `layer`, `layer2`, and `layer3`. If those names are dynamic, then `layers` inside `Network` should be a `ArrayList<Map<String,Layer>>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see. What I actually want is an array of three Layer objects that can be added to the ArrayList inside Network. I changed my JSON so the array has 3 layers and now my ArrayList has 3 layers, but the inputs and outputs are still 0.

Comment: You mean the fields `inputs` and `outputs`?  Those should be `null`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I mean the fields "input" and "output" , the int fields inside Layer

Comment: Please edit your question with the new JSON.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis done

Comment: You still have a level that's unmapped. If you have control of the JSON, just get rid of the `layer`, `layer2`, and `layer3` elements.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that did it. so it was an error in my JSON structure and my expectation/assumption of GSon deserialization. Thanks for the help. Do you want to post an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON (and the respective POJO) structure should probably look like this:

```
    {
      "layers" : [
          {"input":300,output":8000},
          {"input":300,"output":8000},
          {"input":300,"output":8000}
      ]
    }

    public class Layer {
       int input;
       int output;
   }

    public class Network {
        ArrayList<Layer> layers;
    }
```

If each layer also have a name (or a label), it should have the following structure:

```
    {
      "layers" : [
          {"label":"layer", "input":300,output":8000},
          {"label":"layer1", "input":300,"output":8000},
          {"label":"layer2", "input":300,"output":8000}
      ]
    }

    public class Layer {
       int input;
       int output;
       String label;
   }

    public class Network {
        ArrayList<Layer> layers;
    }
```